# Force password change on next sign in

Tags: customer, magento-2.1, password

Is it possible to force a customer to change their password on next sign in?

Just to be clear, I don't mean sending them an email to reset it - rather when they log in they are prompted to do so.

Comment: That's not possible out of the box afaik. But you can create an observer to check on the login event and then redirect customers to the account details page from their customer dashboard to update their password.

Answer (score 1):

As Anna pointed out, this is not possible out of the box.

I have had to create a database table which simply records if a force password change is required and on login force the user to do this if the Database requires it. This was very easy to implement and has the benefit that should there ever be a reason to require all users to password change (hoping that is never the case) it is easy to do!

Comment: This answer would be improved by some code samples.